# Playing music from a SKAction

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to add background music to my game. I have a switch that will mute the music and when you tap it again it will play the music. 
This is the code to play the music

```
 var backgroundMusic = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Background.wav", waitForCompletion: true)
 runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(backgroundMusic), withKey: "music")
```

I know that the waitForCompletion should be set to false to stop the music when you tap the switch. But when I have it set to false the music doesn't play it just is like the static sound.

```
self.removeActionForKey("music")
```

That is the code I used to stop the music. I was wonder if you can mute the music until the track finished or it there is another way to play music forever in SpriteKit.

Comment: you might be misunderstanding wht waitForComplete does. If it's true, then at the end of the sound file, it will notify the sequence, or foreverAction, that it's done, so that it can then be played again. If it's false, then it tells the forever Action immediately to do the next thing.

Answer (score 1):

`waitForCompletion` : If `true`, the duration of this `action` is the same as the length of the audio playback. If `false`, the `action` is considered to have completed immediately.

Setting `waitForCompletion` to `false`, will create an action with a duration of `0`. Thus the repeat forever action will not function properly.
You have to wait for the duration its playing before playing again from the start, for the music to loop. So set `waitForCompletion` to `true`,

```
 var backgroundMusic = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Background.wav", waitForCompletion: true)
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/playSoundFileNamed:waitForCompletion:

You can stop the music by using `removeActionForKey`.

Comment: would there be any way to stop it when its in the middle of playing

Comment: You can stop the music by using `removeActionForKey`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [ObjectAL](http://kstenerud.github.io/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/) instead of Spritekit for background music. Or here is a simple method I use for background music, borrowed from [SKUtils](https://github.com/raywenderlich/SKTUtils):

```
-(AVAudioPlayer*)setupSound:(NSString*)file volume:(float)volume{
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:file withExtension:nil];
    AVAudioPlayer *s = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    s.numberOfLoops = -1;
    s.volume = volume;
    [s prepareToPlay];
    return s;
}
```

Then you call it as follows:

```
...
AVAudioPlayer *bgplayer = [self setupSound:@"Background.wav" volume:1.0];
...
[bgplayer play];
...
[bgplayer pause];
```

Comment: do you know how to that in swift?